# Using text as condition in a while loop

Tags: matlab, loops, text, while-loop

Im having some trouble with using text as an condition for a while loop, currently the basic coding is:

```
result=struct('val','yes');

while result.val=='yes'
result.val=input('more digits?');
end
```

So as you see, what Im trying to do is keeping the loop going as long as the user types in 'yes'. But thats one of the probelmes I am having; Is there a way to get rid of the need to write the ''(e.g yes instead of 'yes')? Secondly, when I run the code it gives me the error message "Error using  ==  ,Matrix dimensions must agree.". I realise this have to do with the word yes being longer than no, but I don't know how to fix it. It's not really an issue though considering its the the program ends anyway, but it is an annoyance I would like to get rid off.

Comment: What language is this? Looks like it's Matlab, so I've tagged it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, but yes; We are talking matlab

Comment: why not just check the first letter, for example, `result.val(1)=='y'` or `result.val(2)=='n'`. Also, use strcmp to compare strings instead of `==`

Answer (score 3):

To compare strings, use [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html), or `strcmpi` to ignore case.  It will handle comparison of different length strings.  For example:

```
strcmpi(result.val,'yes')
```

If you want to search for a substring, such as just a 'y', at the beginning of the input, consider [`strncmpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) (`strncmpi(result.val,'y',1)`) or just check the first character (`result.val(1)`).